# Name href Label According to User Text Input JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my app, I am letting the user add categories. Each category is a simple href with label that the user entered as a name of category. The problem I am having is the category name is shown (undefined). So I am not sure where is the problem. Also, when I click again on add category, the previously created one disappear!

```js
var boxName="type here"; 
var inputt = document.getElementById("boxName").value;
function addInput()
{
    // var boxName="type here"; 

document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML='<br/><input  type="text" id="'+boxName+'" value="'+boxName+'" /><input type="button" onclick="addlinking()" value="Add"/><span id="Adding"></span>';
var inputt = document.getElementById("boxName").value;
addlinking(inputt);

}
function addlinking(tt){
    document.getElementById('Adding').innerHTML = '<br/><input type="submit" onclick="addinghref()" value="'+tt+'"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a><span id="Linking"></span>';
 
}
function addinghref()
{

    document.getElementById('Linking').innerHTML='<a href="http://google.com"></a>';
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="addInput()" value="Add Category"> 
                       <span id="responce"></span>
```

Comment: Why did you add the jQuery tag while you are not using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var catTemplate = document.getElementById("adding-template")
                          .content
                          .querySelector(".category");
var createCatDiv = document.getElementById('create-cat');
var createCatInput = createCatDiv.querySelector("input[type=text]");

function addInput()
{
  // Clear previous entry.
  createCatInput.value = "";
  // Show the div.
  createCatDiv.classList.remove("hidden");
}

function addlinking()
{
  // Hide the create cat div.
  createCatDiv.classList.add("hidden");
  // Import the category div from the template.
  var catDiv = document.importNode(catTemplate, true);
  document.getElementById("response").appendChild(catDiv);
  // Set the input.
  var input = catDiv.querySelector("input");
  input.value = createCatInput.value;
  // Replace duckduckgo by the address of your link.
  input.onclick = location.assign.bind(location, "https://duckduckgo.com");
}
```

```css
#create-cat {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
#create-cat.hidden {
  display: none;  
}
.category{
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.category input[type=button] {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.category input[type=button]:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
}
.category input[type=button]:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<template id="adding-template">
  <div class="category">
    <input type="button" />
  </div>
</template>

<input type="button" onclick="addInput()" value="Add Category">
<div id="response"></div>
<div id="create-cat" class="hidden">
  <input type="text" placeholder="type here" />
  <input type="button" onclick="addlinking()" value="Add"/>
</div>
```

Comment: the same is here, I don't want the word link to be shown, instead, the category name should be there. I really appreciate your help but still couldn't figure out how to do it

Comment: It was not clear what you wanted so I had actually put both alternative in the code. I updated it.

Comment: I have question, for the button that is created, how to change the background ?as I am getting grey color and tried to fix that but I couldn't

Comment: Have a look at my edit. However, if you are to re-style it, you better use a link instead of a button as going from page to page is the role of links, not of buttons. Your code will be more concise (no need for a onclick listener, just use the href property of the `a` tag), will make your webpage much more accessible (e.g. for blind people), and you can still style your `a` so that it looks like a button if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var boxName = "type here";

var id = boxName.replace(/\s/g, '_');

function addInput() {
  document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML = '<br/><input  type="text" id="' + id + '" value="' + boxName + '" /><input type="button" onclick="addlinking()" value="Add"/><span id="Adding"></span>';
}

function addlinking(tt) {
  var inputt = document.getElementById(id).value;
  document.getElementById('Adding').innerHTML = '<br/><input type="submit" onclick="addinghref()" value="' + inputt + '"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a><span id="Linking"></span>';
}

function addinghref() {
  document.getElementById('Linking').innerHTML = '<a href="http://google.com">Link</a>';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<input type="button" onclick="addInput()" value="Add Category">
<span id="responce"></span>
```

Comment: That was really useful, but once the new category created, when I click on it, the word (Link) is shown beside the category name, this is what I am trying to avoid, I want the category name along with the link to be there (no other word like link or anything else).